# missing the following properties from type Location 'Location': ancestorOrigins, hash, host, hostname etc in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, document, reserved-words

I was trying to create a `mongodb document` like

[image]

When I hover over the `IUserModel`, it was giving such error

> missing the following properties from type Location 'Location': ancestorOrigins, hash, host, hostname, and 9 more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a long time, then I came to know that `location` is reserved keyword for `mongodb`

so I changed `location` to `locatedOn` and error gone :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple .ts file with this:

```
interface Location {
    name: string;
    id: number;
}

const location1: Location = {
    name: 'oakland',
    id: 1,
};
```

The error says:

> Type '{ name: string; id: number; }' is missing the following
> properties from type 'Location': ancestorOrigins, hash, host,
> hostname, and 9 more.

From What I found, I think it is coming from this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location

How ever I don't understand why is giving me a HTML DOM api error when I'm only using typescript.